# IndexError: list index out of range for pyswip library

Tags: python, prolog

First of all I'm getting too many errors for python right now. This situation affected my motivation quite negatively. I'm trying to run an expert system that I found in this error. But I get the following error. I looked at other solutions but it didn't work for me either.

Drug Store Expert System:
https://github.com/enzoftware/pyswipl_drugstore

**Code:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request
from wtforms import Form, TextField, TextAreaField, validators, StringField, SubmitField
from pyswip import Prolog
import os
import time

# App config.
DEBUG = True
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '7d441f27d441f27567d441f2b6176a'



class ReusableForm(Form):

    name = TextField('Name:', validators=[validators.required()])

    @app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def hello():
        form = ReusableForm(request.form)
        if request.method == 'POST':

            name=request.form['name']
            fiebre = request.form.get('fiebre') == 'on'
            nausea = request.form.get('nausea') == 'on'
            diarrea = request.form.get('diarrea') == 'on'
            headache = request.form.get('headache') == 'on'
            print(fiebre, nausea, diarrea, headache)
            os.system('swipl -q -t "program" console.pl')
        if form.validate():
            f = open("file.txt", "r")
            disease = f.read()
            print(disease)
            flash('Hola ' + name + ', por tus sintomas podemos deducir que tienes '+ disease)
        else:
            flash('Error: Debes ingresar tu nombre. ')

        return render_template('hello.html', form=form)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/BAUM-PC/Desktop/Yeni klasör/pyswipl_drugstore-master/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pyswip import Prolog
  File "c:\Users\BAUM-PC\Desktop\Yeni klasör\pyswipl_drugstore-master\pyswip\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pyswip.prolog import Prolog
  File "c:\Users\BAUM-PC\Desktop\Yeni klasör\pyswipl_drugstore-master\pyswip\prolog.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pyswip.core import *
  File "c:\Users\BAUM-PC\Desktop\Yeni klasör\pyswipl_drugstore-master\pyswip\core.py", line 568, in <module>
    (_path, SWI_HOME_DIR) = _findSwipl()
  File "c:\Users\BAUM-PC\Desktop\Yeni klasör\pyswipl_drugstore-master\pyswip\core.py", line 411, in _findSwipl
    (path, swiHome) = _findSwiplWin()
  File "c:\Users\BAUM-PC\Desktop\Yeni klasör\pyswipl_drugstore-master\pyswip\core.py", line 208, in _findSwiplWin
    match = pattern.match(ret[-1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**core.py
(related section)**

```
    try:
        cmd = Popen(['reg', 'query',
            r'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\SWI\Prolog',
            '/v', 'home'], stdout=PIPE)
        ret = cmd.communicate()

        # Result is like:
        # ! REG.EXE VERSION 3.0
        #
        # HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\SWI\Prolog
        #    home        REG_SZ  C:\Program Files\pl
        # (Note: spaces may be \t or spaces in the output)
        ret = ret[0].splitlines()
        ret = [line.decode("utf-8") for line in ret if len(line) > 0]
        pattern = re.compile('[^h]*home[^R]*REG_SZ( |\t)*(.*)$')
        match = pattern.match(ret[-1])
        if match is not None:
            path = match.group(2)

            paths = [os.path.join(path, 'bin', dllName)
                     for dllName in dllNames]
            for path in paths:
                if os.path.exists(path):
                    return (path, None)
```

Comment: error is from your `core.py`, in `match = pattern.match(ret[-1])`, where your  `ret` is an `empty list`,

Comment: I added the related section up. Do I need to change -1 value ?

Comment: It seems like the registry key(`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\SWI\Prolog`) not exit on your system. May be you need to install the [`SWI-Prolog`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/windows.html)?

Comment: In this case, do I have to delete the prolog from the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first error:

As per official [documentation of Pyswip](https://pypi.org/project/pyswip/) you must take care of version of python and SWI-Prolog.

Make sure the SWI-Prolog architecture is the same as the Python architecture. If you are using a 64bit build of Python, use a 64bit build of SWI-Prolog.

For second error:

When you are accessing `ret[-1]` in `match = pattern.match(ret[-1])` the index of list `ret` is not available.

Comment: I've solved my problem. Since python is **32-bit**, I deleted the prolog and installed the **32-bit** prolog. worked this time.

Answer (score 3):

**Windows Solution:**

1. Make sure your Python and SWI Prolog are both 32- or 64-bit.
2. Go to line 180 of core.py and change the line to this:

   `paths = [os.path.join(programFiles, r'swipl\bin', dllName)`

Comment: the 2nd point works! Thank you so much!!!